# Moving a sprite image using arrow keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to animate a robo such that it would move around an HTML5 Canvas.
Here's my image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oecS2.png

The instructions I have to work on my animation are:

1. If you are not pressing a button, the skeleton should not move and should just be facing you.
2. If you press the right arrow key or “d” then it should move to the right.
3. If you press the left arrow key or “a” then it should move to the left.
4. If you press the up arrow key or “w” then it should move up.
5. If you press the down arrow key or “s” then it should move down
6. If it gets to the edge of the canvas, it should keep walking but not move

I haven't been able to find any helpful resources that would guide me to move my sprite image using arrow keys. And I know a bit of making an image move using mouse but not using arrow keys. But here's what I've tried so far.

**JavaScript:**

```
var tID;

function stopAnimate()
{
    clearInterval(tID);
}

function animateScript()
{
    var position = 256;
    const diff = 256;

    tID = setInterval ( () => {
        document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundPosition = `-${position}px 0px`;

        if (position < 1536)
        {
            position = position + diff;
        }
        else
        {
            position = 256;
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Robot.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Animation</h2>

        <div id ="demo">
            <p id="image" onmouseover="animateScript()" onmouseout="stopAnimate()"></p>
        </div>

        <script src="Animate.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}

#image
{
    height: 256px;
    width:  256px;
    background: url('robo.png') 0px 0px;
}
```

The code above isn't the right thing that I need but I was just testing it using my knowledge about moving sprites using a mouse but I need some help on rotating my image using arrow keys. Any help would be appreciated!